# URL rewriting with OcpSoft adds parameter multiple times

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

Im' using OcpSoft rewrite, and I have this only rule for forwarding:

```
@Override public Configuration getConfiguration(ServletContext servletContext) {
    return ConfigurationBuilder.begin().addRule(
                         Join.path("/x/{vendor}/{url}")
                             .to("/vendors/{url}")
           );
}
```

Now, this works fine, I can find the `"vendor"` parameter in my list of parameters, and the `"url"` too.

The problem is that when I debug, I can see that the `vendor` and `url` are present multiple times instead of just once in the list of parameters:

[image]

Here, `{url}` is added 16 (!!) times in my list of parameters.

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is actually a bug of the library: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/223

So, yeah.

Comment: That bug is from 2016, but I'm seeing the same thing happen when I upgraded from the 2.x branch to 3.4.2.  Is there any work around until they get around fixing that bug, which worries me due to the age of the ticket?